# Sending file using AFNetworking and iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, afnetworking

I want to move a subview of my view without deactivating Auto layout, which is useful in other parts of my app.

I was using this code in iOS 7 which was working fine, but is now broken with iOS 8:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.avatar = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    NSString* request = @"/users/";
    [manager
     POST:request parameters: nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
         [formData
              appendPartWithFileData: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.avatar, 1.0)
              name: @"picture"
              fileName: @"new_avatar.jpg"
              mimeType: @"image/jpeg"
         ];
     } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Could not send picture %@ !", error);
     }];
```

I don't understand what is going on, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.avatar, 1.0)` contains the image, and as I said, everything was working fine with iOS7.

**No request is even made to the server...**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22183045/1106035

Comment: @Prince I'm not getting the image the in the same way, and as said in the post, the data is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you upgrade your AFNetwork lib for iOS 8. Because I was facing the same problem but after upgrading, all was working fine again.

Comment: Thanks, I did a `pod update` and it went fine. I thought it was more than that.